Richards’ transformation in \$ \Psi \$ domain
Richards’ transformation in \$ \Psi \$ domain.
$$tanh (\frac {s \tau}{2} - j \pi) = \frac{e^{\frac{s \tau}{2} - j \pi} - 1}{e^{\frac{s \tau}{2} - j \pi} + 1}$$
To evaluate the expression \$\frac{e^{\frac{s \tau}{2} - j \pi} - 1}{e^{\frac{s \tau}{2} - j \pi} + 1}\$, we need to simplify the exponentials and then perform the division.
Given:
$$ z = \frac{s \tau}{2} - j \pi $$
We can rewrite the exponential terms using Euler's formula \$ e^{jx} = \cos(x) + j\sin(x)\$:
$$
e^{\frac{s \tau}{2} - j \pi} = e^{\frac{s \tau}{2}} e^{-j \pi} = e^{\frac{s \tau}{2}} (\cos(\pi) - j\sin(\pi)) = e^{\frac{s \tau}{2}} (-1) = -e^{\frac{s \tau}{2}}
$$
So, our expression becomes:
$$
\frac{-e^{\frac{s \tau}{2}} - 1}{-e^{\frac{s \tau}{2}} + 1}
$$
We can simplify this by multiplying the numerator and the denominator by (-1):
$$
\frac{-e^{\frac{s \tau}{2}} - 1}{-e^{\frac{s \tau}{2}} + 1} = \frac{-(e^{\frac{s \tau}{2}} + 1)}{-(e^{\frac{s \tau}{2}} - 1)} = \frac{e^{\frac{s \tau}{2}} + 1}{e^{\frac{s \tau}{2}} - 1}
$$
Therefore, the simplified expression is:
$$
\frac{e^{\frac{s \tau}{2}} + 1}{e^{\frac{s \tau}{2}} - 1}
$$
However, a thesis (page 30) said this
$$tanh (\frac {s \tau}{2} - j \pi) = tanh (\frac {s \tau}{2})$$

And your question is...

What's wrong with my calculation?

In the beginning you wrote the definition wrong.
The definition of hyperbolic tangent is:
$$
\tanh x=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}=\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}
$$
Therefore
$$
\tanh (\frac {s \tau}{2} - j \pi) = \frac{e^{{s \tau} - j 2\pi} - 1}{e^{{s \tau} - j 2\pi} + 1}
$$
Now evaluate \${e^{{s \tau} - j 2\pi}}\$:
$$
e^{{s \tau} - j 2\pi}=e^{{s \tau}}e^{- j 2\pi} \\
e^x=\cos x + j \sin x \Rightarrow e^{-j2\pi}=1 \\
\therefore e^{{s \tau} - j 2\pi}=e^{{s \tau}}
$$
Therefore
$$
\tanh (\frac {s \tau}{2} - j \pi) = \frac{e^{{s \tau}} - 1}{e^{{s \tau}} + 1}=\tanh \frac{s\tau}{2}
$$

According to my calculations, it appears that the expression given is the same as the cotangent:

